# Python & Selenium | Google Form RadioButton, RandomChoice.click() Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-forms

I used reference from [This guy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217765/submit-random-choices-on-google-form) and update the Selenium to latest format. At Section_One, the code didn't randomly click any radio buttons at all. I am going bananas trying to figure out what went wrong. Just an hobbyist looking to automate his online survey to get respondent for his study..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random

#heart of the code
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python_Projects\googleForm_project\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://forms.gle/JihUB5WZMsFzJrA46")
time.sleep(2)

#pagetwo
pagetwo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/span/span')
pagetwo.click()
time.sleep(2)

#pagethree
pagethree = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span')
pagethree.click()
time.sleep(2)

declaration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/label/div')
declaration.click()

#pagefour
pagefour = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span')
pagefour.click()
time.sleep(2)

screening_question = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i5"]/div[3]/div')
screening_question.click()

#pagefive
pagefive = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span')
pagefive.click()
time.sleep(2)

#section_one

#purposely left (7) & (8) because I don't want the code to choose it
time.sleep(1)
options = [
    [0, 1], #gender
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], #age
    [9, 10, 11, 12], #education_lvl
    [13, 14, 15, 16], #work_exp
    [17, 18], #job_sector
    [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], #occupation
    [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38] #industry
]

#section_one loop
def main(counter):
    count = counter + 1

    #collect all buttons on page and submit button

    #buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i115"]/div[3]/div')
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioOptionContainer']")
    #buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupElContainer")

    for i in range(len(options)):
        buttons[random.choice(options[i])].click()
```

I tried coding using reference from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVFcE4M6lw0&t=716s&ab_channel=PrasunChakraborty) for Section_One

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random

#heart of the code
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python_Projects\googleForm_project\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://forms.gle/JihUB5WZMsFzJrA46")
time.sleep(2)

#pagetwo
pagetwo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/span/span')
pagetwo.click()
time.sleep(2)

#pagethree
pagethree = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span')
pagethree.click()
time.sleep(2)

declaration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/label/div')
declaration.click()

#pagefour
pagefour = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span')
pagefour.click()
time.sleep(2)

screening_question = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i5"]/div[3]/div')
screening_question.click()

#pagefive
pagefive = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span')
pagefive.click()
time.sleep(2)

#section_one

a = random.randint(0, 38)
button_range = random.randint(0, 37)

radio_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupElContainer")
radio_buttons[button_range].click()

    #buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i115"]/div[3]/div')
    #buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioOptionContainer']")
    #buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupElContainer")
```

But I received this error instead;

```
line 46, in <module>
    radio_buttons[button_range].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: This xpath `//*[@class='freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioOptionContainer']` does not return anything for me

Comment: I got that xpath from tutorial I watched on YouTube. But when I inspect elements on GoogleForm, the `//*[@id="i115"]/div[3]/div'` is the right element. I put three xpath, for your guys references. Hope it helps